# Set Text Field from another object ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

I am stuck trying to set and retrieve the text in a `UITextField` object on titleViewController.

I have a Journal object that has a reference to the titleViewController object, but I can not seem to set the text value for the `UITextField`.

I have an outlet to the UITextField object in the titleViewController, and Journal can see it, but when I write to code to set the value nothing happens when it is run.

There is no errors that pop up in XCode or the Log. I know it should work as the set up works for accessing custom methods in other such viewControllers being managed by the same Journal.

-EDIT-

Here is a code sample as requested:

```
//Get viewController from Array
TitleVC *titlePage = [_PageArray objectAtIndex:0];

//Get string from Dictionary
NSString *test = [_saveDictionary objectForKey:@"Name"];

//This is one of the attempts to set the UITextField 
//FIXED by Tomy211(but still does not work)
[titlePage.textName setText:test];

//This is attempting dot notation
titlePage.textName.text = test
titlePage.textName = test //Wrong I know but had to test

//Also made sure test was a proper string
NSLog(test) //Displayed "Dan" as Expected
```

This is in Journal.m which accessed a reference to the titleVC from a storyboard using this code:

```
-(UIViewController *)loadView:(NSString *)viewID{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewID];
    return viewController;
}
```

The ViewController returned from that method is used in displaying the View in a scrollview, and I havent had an issue with accessing methods from the ViewControllers this way.

All I want to do is let Journal.m set and read the value from textName which is an outlet connected to a `UITextField`.

-UPDATE-

I checked and discovered I can read the value of the textField but not write to it.

-FINAL UPDATE-

I found the issue with my code. The code was correct(minus the correction by Tomy211), but the issue was where I was calling the code. I was calling the method before the view was displayed, so when the view did get displayed it revert back to the default values.

Note to all that have similar issues:
Check to make sure the view is being displayed before updating a value of a UIObject part of the view. If you have to update values with the view not displayed, use instance variables and have the UIObject get their values from them on the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Please edit this post to show the code you have tried, and elaborate more on what you're expecting to happen vs. what is actually happening so we are better able to help you.

Comment: Added code and what I am trying to do. As of now, the code does nothing and gives no errors. It is syntax error free, and runtime error free.

Comment: are you sure the `textName` outlet is being assigned correctly in the storyboard?

Comment: Triple checked that. I even reconnected the outlet to the textfield just to be sure

Comment: have you implemented the setTextName method? or its being synthesized from a property? In the code above you are setting the textName object (which i assume is the textField) with an NSString. You should set the text property of the textName object to text. This way
[titlePage.textName setText:text]; One of the declarations above is wrong (and should show a compile error). Which one of the two is it?

Comment: and by one of the two i mean:
1. [titlePage setTextName:test];
2. titlePage.textName.text = test

Comment: @tomi2711 Both of those lines are the same.

Comment: @tomi2711 I used XCode to create the outlet property from the storyboard so it is synthesized. There is no compile time or run time errors with the above code(which is what worries me). I may have to start this part over to trace my steps, but everything should have worked.

Comment: If the UITextField is called textName, both declarations are not the same. [titlePage setTextName:text];  takes a UITextField, not an NSString. The setTextName is the setter generated by the UITextField property. To actually change the text in the UITextField yo should change the "text" property in the UITextField. In the second declaration he is doing this. So 1 and 2 are not the same.

Comment: If textName is a UITextField you should use [titlePage.textName setText:text]; because you want to set the text property of textName. That's why i find strange no compile errors, because he is setting a UITextField with an NSString

Comment: Updated what works and what does not.

Comment: Fixed my problem. See answer and question for solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I tried to update the TextField objects before the view has been loaded.
Moving the method call to after the point I load the view fixes the problem. I have updated my question to reflect what was correct, and what was incorrect.

Note to all that have similar issues: Check to make sure the view is being displayed before updating a value of a UIObject part of the view. If you have to update values with the view not displayed, use instance variables and have the UIObject get their values from them on the viewDidLoad method.